# Trouble with bootstrap-validate and useState (React)

Tags: reactjs, validation, callback, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

I'm using [bootstrap-validate](https://bootstrap-validate.js.org) for my forms, and I'm running into a really weird problem. If I try to use `setIsValidEmail` in the callback then whenever I type [some-text]@[some-text].com . I can't type anything pass the 'c' in 'com'. It works fine if I leave the callback and just remove `setIsValidEmail`.

Repo: https://github.com/mlelien/testtest

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import * as bootstrapValidate from 'bootstrap-validate'

window.bootstrapValidate = bootstrapValidate

const SignUp2 = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [isValidEmail, setIsValidEmail] = useState(false)

  const onEmailChange = (e) => {
    const newEmail = e.target.value
    setEmail(newEmail)

    bootstrapValidate('#form-email', 'email:Invalid email', (isValid) => {
      setIsValidEmail(isValid)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h3>SIGN UP</h3>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="form-email">
            Email address
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control"
              id='form-email'
              aria-describedby='enter email'
              placeholder='Enter email'
              value={email}
              onChange={onEmailChange}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignUp2
```

Comment: Make a sandbox please... https://codesandbox.io

Comment: https://1ebwo.codesandbox.io/

Comment: You posted the app, show the code at the sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-validate-stackoverflow-1ebwo?fontsize=14

Comment: I commented out two lines at the top of signup.js because that's required for webpack, and I wasn't sure how to configure webpack in sandbox